# Form validation for dynamic table tr angular 5

Tags: angular, validation, html-table, disabled-input

I have dynamic `table tr` and each row contains a submit button. I also applied `input` control name dynamically. What is the best way to enable/ disable button based on the `tr` row validation?

```
<form #form1="ngForm">
<table>
<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let value of data; let i=index">
<td><input type="text" name="name{{i}}" #nameInput="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dataModel.name" [value]="value.name" required /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="email{{i}}" #emailInput="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="dataModel.email" [value]="value.email" required /></td>
<td><button type="submit" [disabled]="form1.form.invalid">Submit</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Here, above `[disabled]` condition applies for all rows but i want to apply it based on the each row.

Comment: can you share your ts:

Comment: can you share more code about it?

Comment: Try to wrap every row `<tr></tr>` with a `<form>` tag.

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara I already tried but It is not showing row in the browser (Chrome and Mozilla).

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using ngModel I would suggest you use `FormGroup`.

> TS

```
public form1: FormGroup;
ngOnInit(){
this.form1 = this.fb.group({});
}
```

Once you get the data you can do a form validation.

```
for(index i = 0 ; i < resDeta.length ; index++){
 if (resDeta.req === 'TRUE') {
const control: FormControl = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
 this.form1.addControl(resDeta[index].name, control);
}else{
  const control: FormControl = new FormControl(null);
  this.form1.addControl(props.name, control);
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <form [formGroup]="form1" (ngSubmit)="Submit(form1)">
    <table>
    <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let prop of resDeta; let i=index">
    <td><input type="text" [formControlName]="prop.name" [id]="prop.name" [name]="prop.name" placeholder="Enter {{prop.label}}" class="form-control" [attr.maxlength]="prop.length" [value]="prop.name"></td>

<td><input type="text" [formControlName]="prop.name" [id]="prop.name" [name]="prop.name" placeholder="Enter {{prop.label}}" class="form-control" [attr.maxlength]="prop.length" [value]="prop.email"></td>

    <td><button type="submit" [disabled]="!form1.valid">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i did this using form array in reactive form , may be it's helping you.
attached link below
[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-werwuu)

```
<button (click)="addbutton()">Add</button>
<ul [formGroup]="formName" class="listTable">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>description</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <ul formArrayName="items" class="listTable">
        <li *ngFor="let value of formName.get('items').controls; let ix = index">
            <form [formGroupName]="ix">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" formControlName="name"  required/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" formControlName="description"  required/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="value.invalid">Submit</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```